# Data inside of array is not being displayed in my webpage

Tags: javascript, html, async-await

I am getting metadata from an s3 bucket and modifying it for my own needs. However, I cant seem to be able to display the final data while on the other hand the original data that I pulled is being displayed I am not sure why this is occuring. The general idea of the code is below:

```js
  const [original_data, setOriginal_data] = useState([]);
  const [final_data, setFinal_data] = useState([]);
  const shouldLog = useRef(true);


async function getMetadata() {
  const s3Meta = await list({prefix: '',});
  
  await Promise.all(s3Meta.items.map(async (item) => { 
    const metaResults = await getProperties({
      key: item.key
    })

    //Sorts the metadata into seperate arrays
    await first_function(metaResults);
  }));

  //Count the amount of unique keywords in each array
  await second_function();

}

async function first_function(metaResults){
  //Populate Each Array with their appropriate infomation so as to be used for general 
  //information displays
  setOriginal_data((original_data) => [
    ...original_data,
    metaResults.metadata.a
  ]);}

async function second_function() {
  const counter = [];

  //Counts the amount of times a country appears 
  for (const num of original_data) {
    counter [num] = counter [num] ? counter [num] + 1 : 1;
  }

  //Stores the country and the amount of times it apears in an array
  original_data.forEach(ele => {
      setFinal_data((final_data) => [
        ...final_data, 
        ele + ' ' + counter [ele],
      ]);
  });

  //Filters out duplicates
  setFinal_data((final_data) => [
      ...final_data.filter((item, index) => final_data.indexOf(item) === index),
  ]);}

useEffect(() => {

//Shouldlog is used to prevent the function from running multiple times so as to pull repeated data 
//from s3 bucket
  if(shouldLog.current){
    shouldLog.current = false;
    getMetadata();
  }
}, []);

//HTML portion of the code follows
return (

    {/*Displays the in the arrays data onto the webpage */}
        {original_data.map((item,index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            {item}
          </div>
        ))}

        {final_data.map((item,index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            {item}
          </div>
)
```

I've tried things such calling `getMetadata()` outside the if statement which does work when running the local webpage, but it causes for repeated data to appear thus there is miscounting and once the webpage is refreshed the display for the array data disappears. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `shouldLog` to the array in the `useEffect` call, like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(shouldLog.current){
    shouldLog.current = false;
    getMetadata();
  }
}, [shouldLog]);
```

This allows `useEffect` to see the updated value of `shouldLog` each time the component rerenders. As it stands now, it will only run on the first render.

Not sure if that will solve your entire problem but it's something that definitely needs to be fixed.

Comment: Made the change but the issue still persists.